# how would i match the number of correct guesses?

Tags: java, if-statement, random, contains, retain

I wanted to make a program like a lottery where winning numbers are randomly generated.

I used `(guessednumbers.containsAll(winningnumbers)` if the user guessed all the 6 numbers.

If the user only got to guess 5 digits, what method should I use to count the 5 correct numbers from the random generated ones?

The code would be:

```
System.out.println("The winning numbers were: " + winningNumbers);
System.out.println("Your numbers are: " + guessedNumbers);

guessedNumbers.retainAll(winningNumbers);
System.out.println("Your matched numbers are: " + guessedNumbers);

if (guessednumbers.containsAll(winningNumbers)); {
    System.out.println("Jackpot!");

}
else if (the supposed code if 5 digits were guessed correctly)
    System.out.println("You won a consolation prize!"); }
```

---

class are `java.util.List`, `java.util.Random` and `java.util.ArrayList;`.

data types are all integer.

Comment: Maybe you could start by telling us the actual data types of `winningNumbers` and `guessedNumbers`. Going by the methods you call on them I would guess they are Lists (`java.util.List`), but not leaving us guessing and instead including that information in your question would be a lot better. Are those `List<Integer>` or what  data type are we dealing with?

Comment: yes, the data type of `winningNumbers` and `guessedNumbers` are integer, and `java.util.List` is also used. I'm sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already called `guessednumbers.retainAll(winningNumbers)` the amount of correctly guessed numbers is just the size of `guessedNumbers`.

```
if (guessedNumbers.size() == 5)
    System.out.println("You have guessed exactly 5 numbers correct.");
```